# How to transfer a large number of Rda files to csv files

Tags: r

I have a bunch of folders from 20180101 to 20180331. Each folder has appropriately 500 Rda files. I wonder how can I transfer all these files into csv?

Comment: It might depend on the structure/content of these .Rda files. What do they look like?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
folders <- list.files(".")
for(folder in folders){
  files <- list.files(folder)
  for(file in files){
    path_n_name <- paste0(folder, "/", file)
    raw_read <- readRDS(path_n_name)
    out_path_n_name <- gsub(".rds", ".csv", path_n_name, ignore.case = T)
    write.csv(raw_read, out_path_n_name)
  }
}
```

For example, in your current working directory, there are a bunch of folders. The first line `folders <- list.files(".")` will get all the name of the folders, and then you iterate this vector. In each iteration, you get the name of all files from each folder, then convert them to `.csv`. Note that it only makes sense to save some data types to `.csv` (i.e. dataframe).

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I followed your code, but it shows error: Error in readRDS(path_n_name) : unknown input format.

Comment: Try to print `files` and make sure that it only contains `rds` files. Could you add `print(path_n_name)` after the line `path_n_name <- paste0(folder, "/", file)`?

Comment: Add this line: `files <- files[grepl(".rds", files, ignore.case=TRUE)]` below `files <- list.files(folder)` and see if it works. If it does, it means that there are some files in your directory that aren't `rds` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have rda files, so I change the code **raw_read <- readRDS(path_n_name)** into **raw_read <- load(path_n_name)**. It works! It's a big help!